# In Android Retrofit2 SimpleXml converter not working with minifyEnabled=true

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit, minify, retrofit2

I'm using following dependencies of retofit2 for xml and gson parsing.

> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'
>
> compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

All is working fine and data parsing is correctly in debug and released apk. But when I release apk by using minifyEnabled=true and shrinkResources=true ,then  xml parsing is not working any more. Gson was also causing problem and was resolved by applying SerializedName annotation to each attribute of Model because proguard renames attributes while generating apk which causes parsing issue.

How can i resolve the xml parsing issue as well? I want to use minifyEnabled necessarily.
Following commands are from Progurad Rules File.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**

# SimpleXMLParsing
-keep public class org.simpleframework.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.** { *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.** { *; }

-keepattributes ElementList, Root

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* *;
}


-dontwarn jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.**
```

Comment: Please post your proguard-rules.pro.

Comment: This is hard to debug but one thing I normally do is check logcat and see what line is getting crash (NPE or NoClassFound). Then I will add another rule around that.   In my case, I got a NPE on model properties with Jackson and I kept the data model class.

Comment: I have seen Log in DDMS , there is no crash of such nature.